# Restructure TSV to list of list of dicts

Tags: python-3.x, list

A simplified look at my data right at parse:

```
[
{'id':'group1'},
{'id':'member1', 'parentId':'group1', 'size':51},
{'id':'member2', 'parentId':'group1', 'size':16},
{'id':'group2'},
{'id':'member1', 'parentId':'group2', 'size':21},
...
]
```

The desired output should be like this:

data =

```
[
[
{'id':'group1'},
{'id':'member1', 'parentId':'group1', 'size':51},
{'id':'member2', 'parentId':'group1', 'size':16}
],
[
{'id':'group2'},
{'id':'member1', 'parentId':'group2', 'size':21},
]

]
```

The issue is that it's very challenging to iterate through this kind of data structure because each list contains a different length of possible objects: some might have 10 some might have 3, making it unclear when to begin and end each list. And it's also not uniform. Note some have only `'id'` entries and no `'parentId'` or `'size'` entries.

```
master_data = []
for i in range(len(tsv_data)):
    temp = {}
    for j in range(?????):
        ???
```

How can Python handle arranging vanilla `.tsv` data into a list of lists as seen above?

I thought one appropriate direction to take the code was to see if I could tally something simple, before tackling the whole data set. So I attempted to compute a count of all occurences of `group1`, based off [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435614/how-to-count-occurrences-of-specific-dict-key-in-list-of-dicts):

```
group_counts = {}
for member in data:
    group = member.get('group1')
    try:
        group_counts[group] += 1
    except KeyError:
        group_counts[group] = 1
```

However, this returned:

> 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Which leads me to believe that counting text occurences may not be the solution afterall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fetch all groups to create the new datastructure afterwards add all the items:

```
data = [
    {
        'id': 'group1'
    }, {
        'id': 'member1',
        'parentId': 'group1',
        'size': 51
    }, {
        'id': 'member2',
        'parentId': 'group1',
        'size': 16
    }, {
        'id': 'group2'
    }, {
        'id': 'member1',
        'parentId': 'group2',
        'size': 21
    }, {
        'id': 'member3',
        'parentId': 'group1',
        'size': 16
    }
]

result = {} # Use a dict for easier grouping. 
lastGrpId = 0

# extract all groups
for dct in data:
    if 'group' in dct['id']:
        result[dct['id']] = [dct]

# extract all items and add to groups
for dct in data:
    if 'parentId' in dct:
        result[dct['parentId']].append(dct)

nestedListResult = [v for k, v in result.items()]
```

Out:

```
[
    [
        {
            'id': 'group1'
        }, {
            'id': 'member1',
            'parentId': 'group1',
            'size': 51
        }, {
            'id': 'member2',
            'parentId': 'group1',
            'size': 16
        }, {
            'id': 'member3',
            'parentId': 'group1',
            'size': 16
        }
    ], [{
        'id': 'group2'
    }, {
        'id': 'member1',
        'parentId': 'group2',
        'size': 21
    }]
]
```